# Delphi array conversions between 2D and 1D and back again

Tags: arrays, delphi

I am doing some work with OpenCL for GPU processing of calculations.  OpenCL cannot accept a 2D array passed to it, so my 2D arrays need to be converted to 1D and then back to 2D after processing them.

For 2D to 1D I use code like...

```
i:=0;
for y:=0 to yDim-1 do
begin
     for x:=0 to xDim-1 do
     begin
          FlatArray1[i]:=Array1[x,y];
          FlatArray2[i]:=Array2[x,y];
          FlatArray3[i]:=Array3[x,y];
          FlatArray4[i]:=Array4[x,y];
          FlatArray5[i]:=Array5[x,y];
          inc(i);
     end;
end;
```

I can then pass these 1D arrays as parameters to OpenCL.  The OpenCL processing time is very fast.  Once OpenCL is done the 1D arrays need to be converted back into 2D.

```
x:=0;
y:=0;
for loop:=0 to 1DArraySize-1 do
begin
     Array1[x,y]:=FlatArray1[loop];
     Array2[x,y]:=FlatArray2[loop];
     Array3[x,y]:=FlatArray3[loop];
     Array4[x,y]:=FlatArray4[loop];
     Array5[x,y]:=FlatArray5[loop];
     inc(x);
     if x=xDim then
     begin
          x:=0;
          inc(y);
     end;
end;
```

An example of time ratio is 60 ms for the OpenCL calculations that process the arrays and 550 ms for the array conversion loops.
The 550ms is longer than using CPU alone for calculations so it is killing the advantage OpenCL gives for calculation times.

Are there any clever tricks for more efficiently converting the arrays from 2D to 1D and back again?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Are the arrays dynamic or fixed length? If the former then you don't have a 2D array. You have a jagged array. Delphi doesn't have built in support for dynamic multidimensional arrays. Only dynamic jagged arrays. Its one of the great weaknesses of the language for numerical programming. You likely have to deal with this by using bespoke indexing code to access elements in a 1D dynamic array that is laid out as a multidimensional array.

Comment: Yes, dynamic unfortunately.  The dimensions of the data/array is user configurable. One more entry in the "cons" column for Delphi.  What logic is there to not allocate memory for a dynamic array in a contiguous chunk when a setlength is performed?

Comment: @Some1Else Give us more details with type declarations

Comment: All arrays are dynamic length and contain doubles.  So Array1 is array of array of double.  FlatArray1 is array of double.

Comment: But you can make 1D `array of double` and use `A[y*width+x]` if you need two indices

Comment: What MBo says is what I am talking about.

Comment: So basically rewrite the current code outside the OpenCL to use 1D arrays.  Then I can pass the 1D arrays to/from OpenCL?  May be worth a go.

Comment: "May be worth a go." It's the only way to achieve your stated goal

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ater all those years of experience you have I would have guessed that you have learned that there is no `only way` of doing something. There always exists multiple ways of achieving specific goal. Some better some worst. And what is better or worst depends on specific scenario. There is no `best` solution that would be best in any scenario. I'm surprised you still haven learned that. PS: Check my answer bellow for one of such `other ways` of achieving OP goal.

Comment: @silver Unfortunately you have not understood the question. All of my years developing numerical code that integrates with third party numerical libraries has taught me that the lack of a multidimensional array in Delphi is a huge deficiency.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see my error in understanding the question now. OP is converting five 2D arrays into five 1D arrays while I misunderstood that he is converting one 2D array into five 1D arrays.

Comment: Converting the surrounding code to 1D arrays fixed the OpenCL slowdown.  BUT it also sped up the CPU only code by nearly a factor of 3.  So whatever Delphi is doing to support 2D arrays is not optimal.  So now even without needing to flatten the 2D arrays, the OpenCL code is still slower than CPU only code using 1D arrays.  Maybe that will help someone else if they have a similar issue.  Thanks again for all the tips and pointing me in the right direction.  I would mark @DavidHeffernan correct, but I cannot "tick" a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest conversion is avoiding conversion at all.

You can have one data copy in memory and cast it to one-dimensional or 2D array. But note the x should be the second dimension for consistent data layout. It is not possible if 2D array is dynamic (it does not occupy single memory region).

Simple example without thorough type checking (perhaps OpenCL function needs just address of data):

```
procedure XX(p:PByteArray);
begin
  Inc(p[47]);
end;
type
  TArr2D = array[0..5, 0..7] of Byte;
  PArr2D = ^TArr2D;
  TArr1D = array[0..47] of Byte;
var
  A: TArr2D;
begin
  A[5,7] := 57;
  XX(@A);
  Caption := A[5,7].ToString;
```

Also it is possible to use `absolute` directive to share the same data, and records with variants where two fields share the same  memory too.

```
procedure YY(var B: TArr1D);
begin
  Dec(B[47]);
end;

var
  A: TArr2D;
  AA: TArr1D absolute A;
begin
  A[5,7] := 57;
  YY(AA);
  Caption := A[5,7].ToString;
```

Answer (score -1):

Some say that because in Delphi dynamic 2D arrays are declared as `array of array of [some type]` this is a weakness of language which makes working with them much harder in compared to other programming languages.

Well I disagree. Granted it does require a bit different thinking. In the end this can even be an advantage that is if you do know how to use it. How?

Well when you declare `array as array of array of [some type]` the outer dimension of this 2D array is actually array of references to 1D array that represent inner dimension of the said 2D array. We can use this to our advantage since we can assign any such reference from the outer dimension of our 2D array to another variable of the same type of inner arrays.

So if you declare your 2D array like:

```
type
  //1D array that will prepresent inner dimension of 2D array
  T1DArr = array of Integer;
  //1D array that stores references to 1D arrays of inner dimension
  //which in fact turns this into 2D array.
  T2Darr = array of T1DArr;
```

you can then work with 2D array in a way you area already familiar with

```
var
  A1DArr: T1DArr; //Declare variable for 1D array
  A2Darr: T2DArr; //Declare variable for 2D array
begin
  //Set dimension of 2D array
  SetLength(A2DArr,10,10);
  //Set value to specific item of the 2D array
  A2DArr[X,Y] := 15;
```

But you can then assign reference of any of the inner dimension arrays to separate variable using:

```
//Assign reference to inner array with index of 1 to 1D array variable
A1DArr := A2DArr[1];
```

EDIT: But how does this help you in converting your 2D array into one 1D array.

As part of built in functionality to work with arrays Delphi includes ability to easily join multiple dynamic arrays into one. So no need to move data from 2D array into 1D array by accessing each array item individually inside a nested loop.

You can use system [System.Concat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Concat) procedure to join two dynamic arrays together.

Or you can just use add operator like so

```
A1Darr := A2DArr[0] + A2DArr[1];
```

This joins inner arrays of 2D array with index 0 and 1 into one 1D array

PS: Another thing that you should change in your code is to work one one array at time. In your code you have nested loop inside which you are working on five different arrays. It would be better to have five separate nested loops one for each array. Why?

When you access first item of an array part of that array is pushed on a stack. But when you access the second item of that array part of the data from that array is already present on stack so access is much faster.

Now this won't work if you are often jumping between different arrays and you would end up pushing data on stack much more often which can in the end hurt performance as it negates purpose of stack.

Comment: The entire array needs to be contiguous because we need to operate on the entire array as a whole, and not the inner slices. You have not understood the question. -1

Comment: Well it seems I got confused by the fact that OP states `I can then pass these 1D arrays as parameters to OpenCL` thinking that the has only one 2D array that he needs to pas to OpenCL as 1D arrays while in fact he has five 2D arrays that he is transforming into 1D arrays.